# Prevent PowerGUI from truncating the output

Tags: powershell, powergui

I'm trying to get an output from a powershell command. However The output is truncated.

```
[PS] >Get-QADGroup "admins"

Name                           Type            DN
----                           ----            --
Admins                         group CN=Admins,OU=Profiles,OU=Groups,OU=Sw...
```

How do I tell this shell wannabe not to truncate its data?

Comment: add format pipes like   Format-Wide or Format-List , http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347677.aspx

Answer (score 47, accepted):

```
Get-QADGroup "admins" | Ft -autosize -wrap
```

If space console is to small try:

```
Get-QADGroup "admins" | Fl name,type,dn
```

**edit:**

```
Get-QADGroup "admins" | Ft -autosize | out-string -width 4096
```

Comment: Is there a way to get no wrap at all?

Comment: Just -autosize isn't enougth? -wrap reduce unused space between column.

Comment: try this: Get-QADGroup "admins" | Ft -autosize | out-string -width 4096 . I use this when I need an out-clipboard or out-file.

Comment: Works great with `| Ft -autosize | out-string -width 4096`.

Comment: Stop thinking in strings!  Use the objects Luke.

Comment: @JasonMArcher I know this is an old post but can you show your possible answer using Objects? I'm just starting to learn and I think this can be useful for the future.

Comment: Still can't believe this is the default behavior of POSH. Really sucks

Comment: `Format-Table` has to parse the entire output before showing anything. Is there something that will output objects immediately wrapping without truncating? Especially if I've selected only one property.

Answer (score 4):

This will prevent all output result truncating -

- Run this and first to view the default enumeration limit.
  `$FormatEnumerationLimit`
- Set the above to **-1** to avoid truncating
  `$FormatEnumerationLimit=-1`

Comment: Not quite sure if there are other conditions, but it didn't work for me. Still seeing truncated results.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue - I increased the buffer size and window size of the powershell window I was running the commands in. It did not truncate in the powershell window nor the output file.